# How to remove (only) the parent element when screen size < 875px in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive

For a component I have made a LINK element around the element so it can function as a link. But this only needs to be on desktop. On mobile (max-width:875) the Link should be removed. How can I do this?

On mobile it should not work as a button.

The thing is, I can't use display:none the  because this will remove the whole element.

I have commented which link has to be removed.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import LogoMobileHero from '../assets/logo-diensen_project.svg';

class HeroMain extends Component {
  state = { showMenu: false };

  toggleMenu = () => {
    this.setState({
      showMenu: !this.state.showMenu,
    });
  };



  render() {
    const { showMenu } = this.state;
    const menuVis = !showMenu ? 'hideDiv' : '';
  

    return (
      <div onClick={this.toggleMenu}>
        {/* This line beneath should remove */}
        <a href="/projecten/" className="mobileNot"> 
        <div className='hero-element'>
          <article>
            <div className='hero-element-titel'>
              <LogoMobileHero
                className='desktop-hero-logo projecten-logo'
                fill='#73a400'
              />
              <LogoMobileHero
                className='mobile-hero-logo mobile'
                fill='#73a400'
              />
              <span className='mobile-hero-button'>
                <span>{'>'}</span>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div className='hero-element-text'>
              <p>
                Het gebruik van rope access is efficiënt en effectief. Door het
                gebruik van gespecialiseerde rope access technieken zijn wij in
                staat op moeilijke toegankelijke locaties werkzaamheden uit te
                voeren.
              </p>
            </div>
          </article>
          <div className='hero-element-image'>
            <a href='/projecten/' className='hero-element-image__link'>
              Projecten
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

        {menuVis ? (
          <> </>
        ) : (
          <article className="home-hero-mobile mobile">
            <div className={`mobile container-info-mobile project`}>
              <p>
                Het gebruik van rope access is efficiënt en effectief. Door het
                gebruik van gespecialiseerde rope access technieken zijn wij in
                staat op moeilijke toegankelijke locaties werkzaamheden uit te
                voeren.
              </p>
              <a href='/projecten/'>projecten</a>
            </div>
          </article>
        )}
        {/* This line beneath should remove */}
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HeroMain;
```

Comment: css media query

Comment: Like I said, display none does not work, visibility:hidden same. Or do you have a different CSS idea?

Comment: by removed you mean to hide that link right?

Comment: Yes, I want to hide/remove it when on mobile.

Comment: @boxdox - But critically (reading the question), the *children* must always be visible. It's only the link that the OP wants "not there" on mobile.

Comment: so use media queries in css. the given answer is good

Comment: @boxdox - Please read the question closely, as well as my comment above. The given answer and your comment won't do what the OP has said they want. That approach will hide the children as well.

Comment: @VictorLaforga - If you're wondering, no, your question is not unclear. I can think of any number of kludgy ways to do it, but I'd love to see a non-kludgy way.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what is `children`? OP just wants to hide the link with class `mobileNot`. That's what I got from the question. Edit: Okay, on another look at the code, I can see OP has nested all his `div` inside the link. Adding `display: none` would hide the whole link anyhow

Comment: So all elements in the LINK should stay. Only the opening and closing tag of <a> should be removed.

Comment: @boxdox - "children" in the standard DOM/HTML sense: The child elements inside the `a` element. So if it were just `<a href="/whatever"><span>x</span></a>`, the OP wants only the `a` element to be not there, but still awnts the `span` element with the `x`. Edit: Yes, exactly. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what is the kludgy way?

Comment: @VictorLaforga - I can think of a couple. :-D Say you had a `DesktopLink` component that renders these links and puts its children inside them. One approach would be for it to *not* render the `a` (just use a fragment) if `screen.width`/`screen.height` (or a [`matchMedia` query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)) said not to. Or perhaps it always renders the `a` but includes a click handler that checks whether it should prevent the default based on the screen size (but that's fairly hostile to accessibility). If it did/didn't render the `a`, you might have...

Comment: ... it use something like the [`useMedia` hook](https://usehooks.com/useMedia/) that lets you re-render when a media query result changes. What I'd **like** to see is a clean CSS solution along the lines of `pointer-events` (but I don't think you can do it with `pointer-events`).

Comment: I know how to do it with React with hooks, but i guess its not hard to replace useState and useEffect hook right ? for useEffect it should be onMount ?  and for state I have not idea what is the equivalent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know how to do this by using React with hooks but the idea should be useful for you,

```
 const [showLink, setShowLink] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)").matches) {
      setShowLink(false);
      // alert("matches");
    } else {
      setShowLink(true);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <a
      href={showLink ? "https://www.google.com" : ""}
      style={
        showLink
          ? { textDecoration: "underline", color: "blue" }
          : { textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }
      }
    >
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
      </div>
    </a>
  );
}
```

I checking to see the screen size onMount so it will happen only once.

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)").matches) {
      setShowLink(false);
      // alert("matches");
    } else {
      setShowLink(true);
    }
```

I have a state called showLink which is initialised with a value of true, i am checking to see if the width is more than 700px meaning that it is for tablets and above, I am changing the showLink to false.

```
 <a
      href={showLink ? "https://www.google.com" : ""}
      style={
        showLink
          ? { textDecoration: "underline", color: "blue" }
          : { textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }
      }
    >
```

I am doing some conditional rendering by checking the showLink value, if true then the href will be linking to google, if not then it will be empty so it wont link anywhere.  Using the same tactic I am giving it conditional styles to make it look like a link or to make it look like a normal element based on the showLink value.

hope this helps :)